# @DELETE method is not supporting(Non-body HTTP method cannot contain @Body or @TypedOutput.)

Tags: java, retrofit, rx-java

```
@DELETE("/job/deletejob")
 Observable<JobDeleteResponseModel> jobDelete( @Body JobDeleteRequestModel model);
```

am getting this error:

> Non-body HTTP method cannot contain @Body or @TypedOutput

Comment: Try Query instead of Body as Bodies on DELETE requests have no defined semantics. Note that
sending a body on a DELETE request might cause some existing
implementations to reject the request.

Comment: Check this link it might help u https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/458

Answer (score 256, accepted):

I've used this official workaround recently:

```java
@HTTP(method = "DELETE", path = "/job/deletejob", hasBody = true)
Observable<JobDeleteResponseModel> jobDelete(@Body JobDeleteRequestModel model);
```

Comment: Not working. I have used in below link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48539478/custom-http-method-not-working-in-retrofit-2#

Can you please help.

Comment: working fine. i trapped in whole day and going to change my api method from backend ,but you save my day..thanks

Comment: `path` is not mandatory if your first argument to interface method is a url annotated with @Url . More here details here : stackoverflow.com/a/62920127/8956093

Answer (score 25):

You need to specify parameters 
 method, path, hasBody
**Kotlin way**

```
@HTTP(method = "DELETE", path = "event/eventRemovePicture", hasBody = true)
fun callDeleteImage(
    @Body body: RequestBody
): Call<RemoveEventPictureResponse>
```

Answer (score 15):

I had similar error.

In my case I was using `@GET` in Interface but then I corrected it to `@POST` method and it worked.

Comment: Thank you, same happened with me , because i copy-pasted methods

Comment: Accidently, I did too. But yeah It doesn't make sense to make a get request with `@Body` verbs.

Answer (score 13):

## try this it's work

```
@HTTP(method = "DELETE", path = "api/v3/delete", hasBody = true)
Call<ResponseBody> RESPONSE_BODY_CALL(@Header("Authorization") String authorization, @Body HashMap<String, List> stringListHashMap);
```

or check
https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/974

Answer (score 8):

Change

```
@DELETE("/job/deletejob")
Observable<JobDeleteResponseModel> jobDelete( @Body JobDeleteRequestModel model);
```

to

```
@HTTP(method = "DELETE", path = "/job/deletejob", hasBody = true)
Observable<JobDeleteResponseModel> jobDelete( @Body JobDeleteRequestModel model);
```

The difference is in

```
@DELETE("/job/deletejob") // For DELETE without body
@HTTP(method = "DELETE", path = "/job/deletejob", hasBody = true) // For DELETE with body
```

Answer (score 5):

Kotlin Code :

`path` is not required if your first argument to interface method is a url annotated with @Url
Example :

```
@HTTP(method = "DELETE", hasBody = true)
fun deleteStudentFromDatabase(
    @Url url: String,
    @Body payload: StudentModel
 ): Observable<Any>
```

If first argument to interface method is not a url then use this

```
    @HTTP(method = "DELETE", path = "{urlPath}", hasBody = true)
    fun deleteStudentFromDatabase(
        @Body payload: StudentModel,
        @Path("urlPath") url: String
     ): Observable<Any>
```

Answer (score 2):

Retrofit 2, i have change the below code from this

```
@DELETE("example/user/{id}/list")
suspend fun deleteUserList(@Path(value = "id", encoded = false)key: Int, @Body request: DeleteUserListRequest): Response<BaseResponse>
```

to

```
@HTTP(method = "DELETE", path = "example/user/{id}/list",hasBody = true)
suspend fun deleteUserList(@Path(value = "id", encoded = false)key: Int, @Body request: DeleteUserListRequest): Response<BaseResponse>
```

Above code is working for me

Answer (score 1):

```
@HTTP(method = "DELETE", path = "{urlPath}", hasBody = true)
```

Also this is working fine. It happens because the request contains a body but we have not defined that yet.

Answer (score 1):

**Kotlin with suspend function.**
By default DELETE method do not supports body. You should explicitly enable it.

```
@HTTP(
    method = "DELETE",
    path = "path/to/api/{someRoute}/{id}", 
    hasBody = true
)
suspend fun delete(
    @Path("someRoute") someRoute: String,
    @Path("id") id: String,
    @Body body: SomeBodyModel,
): Response<Unit>
```

**Use it something like this**

```
suspend fun delete(model: SomeBodyModel) {
    val response = api.delete(model)
    if (!response.isSuccessful) throw HttpException(response)
}
```