# Custom HTTP method not working in Retrofit 2

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, okhttp

Hello I have used custom method in my code as below but it always gives me

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: method AUTH must not have a
>   request body.

My code is not working it always says: `Custom method AUTH, must not have a Body`

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json") 
@HTTP(method = "AUTH", path = "login/{deviceId}", hasBody = true) 
Call<Success> getLogin( @Path("deviceId") int deviceId, @Body RequestBody password);
```

I am using below dependancies.

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
```

Can you please help me.

Comment: so remove the `@Body RequestBody password`. what is the request method that you are supposed to do? GET?POST?PUT?

Comment: I need to pass the password in a body as raw data: {"password":"*****"}. Also I am using custom http mehod as given in:
https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/07d1f3de5e0eb11fb537464bd14fdbacfc9e55a7/retrofit/src/test/java/retrofit/RequestBuilderTest.java#L52-L64

Comment: what is the uri that you have to send the request? is it auth/login/{deviceId} ? what method do you have to execute?

Comment: No, URL is: http://serverurl/login/{deviceId} and AUTH is Custom method name

Comment: why are you making up http methods? Read https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/193821/are-there-any-problems-with-implementing-custom-http-methods tldr don't use custom methods

Comment: it is the requirement to use custom AUTH method to call API, Backend developer put such restrictions.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and after searching into the documentation, I found that the problem was `retrofit` version, try using version `2.4.0` or higher.

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
```