# Non-body HTTP method cannot contain @Body

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

Getting mentioned Error in Retrofit

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Non-body HTTP method cannot contain @Body.
        for method AuthApi.fetchUser
        at retrofit2.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:54)
        at retrofit2.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:43)
        at retrofit2.RequestFactory$Builder.build(RequestFactory.java:213)
        at retrofit2.RequestFactory.parseAnnotations(RequestFactory.java:67)
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(ServiceMethod.java:26)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:202)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:160)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:813)
        at $Proxy2.fetchUser(Unknown Source)
        at org.app.profile.repository.ProfileRepository$fetUser$2.invokeSuspend(ProfileRepository.kt:12)
```

I have set request as

```
@GET("fetchUser")
    suspend fun fetchUser(
        @Body request: JsonObject
    ): Response<ResProfile>
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Already check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37942474/delete-method-is-not-supportingnon-body-http-method-cannot-contain-body-or-t

Comment: is used @POST and my issue fixed